# Can't Shuffle my Card Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Quick question about shuffling an array in c++

For some reason my Cards have the correct Numbers and Suits before I shuffle them. After I do.... All the values on the cards turn to 1 and the suits disappear... weirdest thing ever.

Any help would be great!

```
const int Deck::RANKS[13] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
const char Deck::SUITS[4] = {'H','D','C','S'};
Card cards[52];
int cardNum = 0;


Deck::Deck() : size(0)
{
    cardNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cards[size] = Card(RANKS[i],SUITS[j]);
            cout << "Card Created with " << RANKS[i] << " and " << SUITS[j] << "\n";
            size++;
        }
    }

    shuffle();

    for(int x = 0; x < 52; x++)
    {
        Card c = cards[x];
        cout << "Card Contains " << c.value << " and " << c.suit << "\n";
    }

}

Deck::~Deck() {}

void Deck::shuffle()
{

    size = MAX_SIZE;
    std::random_shuffle(begin(cards), end(cards));
}
```

Some output

```
Card Created with 13 and C
Card Created with 13 and S
Card Created with 14 and H
Card Created with 14 and D
Card Created with 14 and C
Card Created with 14 and S
```

//AFTER SHUFFLING

```
Card Contains 1 and 
Card Contains 1 and 
Card Contains 1 and 
Card Contains 1 and
```

Card.cpp

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <iostream>



using namespace std;

Card::Card(int value, char suit)
{
    value = value;
    suit = suit;
}

Card::Card() {}

bool Card::isPair(Card two)
{
    cout << value << " " << two.value << "\n";
    return (value == two.value);
}
```

Comment: yes i think the error may be in the class card because in the fist loop you print the arrays directly while in the second you query the contents of the cards

Comment: Interesting comment. I'll experiment with that. @MelvinAcuñaGuntanis

Comment: Your Card constructor is broken. `value=value` does nothing to `this->value`. If in the Deck ctor you printed cards themselves you would see the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here. You are assigning the parameters to themselfs.

```
Card::Card(int value, char suit)
{
    value = value;
    suit = suit;
}
```

You can use the this keyword

```
Card::Card(int value, char suit)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->suit = suit;
}
```

but the way to go is using list initialization as stated in the comments.

Comment: Is there any kind of (self.) or (this.) in c++?

Comment: @k9b: You can use a member initialization list `Card::Card(int value, char suit) : value(value), suit(suit) {}`

Comment: upps yea the way to go would be using list intialization

Comment: I was about to go into MoveAssignability and MoveConstructability conditions. Good catch!

Comment: This is why I never name member variables the same as function arguments. The argument `suit` is assigned to the member variable `_suit` and `value` to `_value`. No ambiguity and no accidental shadowing.